# How to access instance code already deployed on GCP Standard App engine long back

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-cloud-debugger

In Google Cloud Platform's App Engine Standard environment, we used to have the "Debug" option through the cloud debugger, which allowed us to review snapshots of code in recent versions. However, it seems this option has been deprecated, and I'm now unable to access the code. Are there alternative methods or tools available that allow us to access and analyze the code for recent versions of our deployed application? Your insights would be greatly appreciated.

I tried reading multiple GCP article but so far no answers for Nodejs application upload to Standard app engine.

Comment: See if this [blog article](https://nocommandline.com/blog/how-to-download-your-source-code-from-google-app-engine-standard-env/) from us helps. Look for the subsection, ```Background```, which explains about lifecycle of uploaded artifacts and then the subsection, Download (DIY) which gives one method for downloading your source code (if you meet the conditions explained in the lifecycle section)

Answer (score 1):

According to the information provided in this documentation: [Cloud Debugger deprecation](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/deprecations/debugger-deprecation)

Also said in the docs that there is a possible work around to help with the debugging needs after the shutdown of the Cloud Debugger.

[Snapshot Debugger](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/snapshot-debugger#snapshot-debugger) is an open-source tool for cloud apps. It lets you check the app's status while it's running, without slowing it down. Unlike traditional debuggers, it's always on and captures snapshots from any part of the app.

You can use it in testing, development, and production stages. It adds less than 10ms to request time when capturing app state, usually unnoticed by users.

To know more about the set-up: [CLI Command Reference](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/snapshot-debugger#cli-command-reference)

Note:

- Cloud Debugger was deprecated on May 16, 2022 and the service was shut down on May 31, 2023.
- Python 2.7 will not be supported by Snapshot Debugger